# From a bunch of files, get filenames which don't have a given word

Tags: shell, unix, command-line, terminal

I have a bunch of files and I want to get the filenames of those files which don't have a given word in their contents.

I would like to do this by a single line statement in the shell.I know it is not tough to get filenames of the files which do contain a given word.

The following would give me all files which contain a given word.

```
find . | xargs grep -l "someword" | uniq
```

**Update:** 
I thought that grep only works on a per line basis, but that's not true. So the above command can be changed to:

```
find . | xargs grep -l "someword"
```

And hence comes the obvious answer to the question:

```
find . | xargs grep -L "someword"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
find . | xargs grep -L "someword" | uniq
```

Comment: This is crazy, I didn't expect this to work. Thanks. My worry was that it would give you an output on a per line basis. But I guess that's not true, which also means that we don't need `uniq`.